# Change data of a view in adapterview in android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapterview

I'm confronted with a new issue, the situation I'm facing is as follows :

I have a `ListView` when I click an element, I use `startActivityForResult` to go a new `ListView` from which the user can grab a piece of information which sent back to the first `ListView` by finishing the `Activity` and sending back the result.

Now, I would like to be able to display this result in the row that was clicked, but I don't get how to navigate inside the views of the adapter.
The only option I'm seeing right now is to tag each view in my adapter and grab it later, with this tag. Is there any better way?

(Each row in my `ListView` is composed with 2 `TextView` and an `ImageView`, I'd like to put the result in the 2nd `TextView`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a way to avoid tagging..

you start a new activity after you get a click , so in `onItemClick`

```
private TextView secondText;

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View contentView, int position, long Id) {
            // get access to the textView you want to change by
                        secondText = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        }
```

changing the text in the onActivityResult should be easy as you have access to the textView already.

Comment: This is an interesting way of getting around my issue, I'll have a go at this and see how it goes. I'm fortunate I don't have 5k elements in my ListView though, or i would have had quite a few TextViews to create...